# webhook.php file is not loading when user submits facebook lead form

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-webhooks

I have created an App for Facebook Leads Integration in my developers account where I've set up all the configurations and settings according to the following video:
https://www.facebook.com/marketingdevelopers/videos/883648801749520/

But whenever I submit any lead form, I am not getting any lead data. When I checked I found that webhook.php file is not getting accessed when the form is submitted. Although when I send the test lead from the webhook test page the file is accessed.

[image]

This lead was recorded in the logs.

It was working very fine since last few months but it suddenly stopped working.
I've also tried to create new page access token but that also did not work since the webhook file was not accessed.
What could be the issue?

**Update:**
Following are the steps I followed:

1. Submitted the app for review. (FB rejected "manage_pages" permission)
2. Contacted the FB Developer Support Team. I created the test app as suggested by them and they checked the configurations and settings from their end.
3. The team suggested to re-upload the screencast video needed for the "manage_pages" permission explaining how I am using that permission.
4. I did so but the review was again rejected.

**New Update:**
I successfully completed my app review. But now there is a new problem.
The leads are properly getting tracked when I test them from the following link:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lead-ads-testing/

But when I try to send the lead from the following URL, it doesn't even reach the webhook file. I can say this confidently because I have created logs at the start of the webhook file.
https://business.facebook.com/facebook_page/publishing_tools/?section=LEAD_ADS_FORMS

Comment: What exactly is a "lead form"? If that is hosted on your server and it triggers some PHP file on your server, you should try to debug the problems between your files. We cannot, as you have not shown any code

Comment: A lead form is a normal form which is displayed on facebook as sponsored Ad. These are hosted on FB server and it triggers PHP file from our server when the user submits this form.

Comment: If this needs `manage_pages` permission to work, then you will need to get that reviewed, before it will actually work in live mode. Try and follow this guide for apps that do not actually involve any end-user facing UI, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/server-to-server-apps

Comment: My app got approved yesterday, finally, but now when I am testing the leads from following link.  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lead-ads-testing/   I am getting "The page admin who installs the app has ceased being an admin" 100 error. I unsubsribed the leadgen app as explained in the following question and subscribed it again, but with no results.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481419/facebook-adgen-the-page-admin-who-installs-the-app-has-ceased-being-an-admin