# Facebook Adgen The page admin who installs the app has ceased being an admin

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-webhooks

In the leadgen testing tool I keep getting this below error .

```
The page admin who installs the app has ceased being an admin
```

I am not understanding what is the next step here. can some one please help ?

Subscribed Field - leadgen
Status - failure
Error Code - 100
Reason - The page admin who installs the app has ceased being an admin

Comment: The person who installed this app on the page is not an admin of the page any more … so have a current page admin re-install it.

Comment: @04FS I am the admin of the page. YOu mean page subscribing to the app ?

Comment: That is probably what they mean by installing the app in this context, yes.

Comment: @04FS It worked !!! Thank you.. However I keep getting error on accessing individual lead_ids                                                                                                  `/3.2/<leadgen_id> . Unsupported get request. Object with ID '<obj id>' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api`

Comment: Hi, I am also getting the same error.  I unsubscribed the app from my developers FB account, but I am still facing the issue.  Is the subscription procedure different than this?

Comment: @DineshPatil You need to resubscribe app to the page.